# Shuting down makes power LED blink

Tags: server, power-management, shutdown, 18.10

I have an Ubuntu 18 server (no GUI). When I shutdown the computer, everything shuts down (power supply, fans, etc), but the power LED is blinking like it's on stand-by.

The shutdown line I'm executing is:

```
sudo shutdown -h now
```

**Note:** Having Windows installed on this computer is correctly shutting down the computer (no blinking).

**Is the computer safely shutdown? Is there a way for me to test this theory?**

Comment: You have tagged EOL release Ubuntu 18.10 which is off-topic due to it's EOL status. The only supported questions allowed for EOL releases is how to upgrade to a supported release.  Ubuntu 19.04 (the only tested & supported upgrade path from 18.10 without re-install) is approaching it's final week of supported life, so your upgrade path will close soon, so I'd suggest upgrading asap. https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic   *Use a LTS release if you don't like release-upgrading every 6-9 months.*

Comment: The obvious way is to check your system logs; many servers record power on, power off times in logs.  (*I'm not talking about OS logs, but the hardware logs kept by your server*)